# Eliminar dos o mas espacios en blanco expresion regular

Tags: java, string, regex

Necesito de su ayuda debido a que tengo una expresion regular para eliminar dos o más espacios en blanco, pero he intentado de varias maneras y no logro obtener el resultado esperado, me pueden orientar por favor.

**Caso No. 1**

```
String texto = "  95716 B VO  21513836                        269     60 S          50.40          3024.00          SI          DCBO040818BLA";
texto = texto.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
```

**Caso No. 2**

```
String texto = "  95716 B VO  21513836                        269     60 S          50.40          3024.00          SI          DCBO040818BLA";
texto = texto.replaceAll("\\s"," ");
```

**Caso No. 3**

```
String texto = "  95716 B VO  21513836                        269     60 S          50.40          3024.00          SI          DCBO040818BLA";
texto = texto.replaceAll(" +"," ");
```

**Caso No. 4**

```
String texto = "  95716 B VO  21513836                        269     60 S          50.40          3024.00          SI          DCBO040818BLA";
texto = texto.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").trim();
```

**Caso No. 5**

```
String texto = "  95716 B VO  21513836                        269     60 S          50.40          3024.00          SI          DCBO040818BLA";
texto = texto.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").replaceAll("^\\s*","").replaceAll("\\s*$","");
```

**Caso No. 6**

```
String texto = "  95716 B VO  21513836                        269     60 S          50.40          3024.00          SI          DCBO040818BLA";
texto = texto.replace("  "," ");
```

**Resultado Esperado**

```
String texto = "95716 B VO 21513836 269 60 S 50.40 3024.00 SI DCBO040818BLA";
```

Comment: Amigo lo que quieres es eliminar todos los espacios en blanco del principio y final de la cadena y dejar solo un espacio en blanco entre las palabras?

Comment: @Diegos Sánchez, efectivamente deseo dejar solo un espacio entre palabras eliminando el resto de espacios

Comment: ok espérame te preparare un ejemplo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

prueba esto:

```
String texto = " Esto  es una     prueba    ";
        texto=texto.trim();
        texto=texto.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
        System.out.println(texto);
```

La funcion "trim" te quitara los espacios en blanco que existan al principio y al final de tu cadena.

Y esta linea de código:

```
texto=texto.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
```

Se interpreta asi, reemplaza 2 o mas espacios en blanco por un solo espacio.

Saludos.

Comment: Amigo efectivamente estoy de acuerdo contigo no me había fijado que esta usando java jjejej ok yo puse ejemplos de javascript, de todos modos los dejare por si alguien los llega a ocupar. Si funciona tu método ya lo comprobé.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo espero y esto te sirva :).

Primera Opción.

```js
var texto = "  95716 B VO  21513836                        269     60 S          50.40          3024.00          SI          DCBO040818BLA";
texto_2 = texto.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "");
console.log(texto_2);
```

Segunda Opción:

```js
var string="  95716 B VO  21513836                        269     60 S          50.40          3024.00          SI          DCBO040818BLA";
                   
string3= string.trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
                   
 console.log(string3);
```