# Reemplazar utilizando expresiones regulares(sintaxis JavaScript) en C++

Tags: javascript, c++, regex

Estoy utilizando expresiones regulares en C++ (`std::regex`) para reemplazar los espacios que se agreguen al principio y al final y solo aceptar un espacio entre palabras.

C++ utiliza la "misma" sintaxis que JavaScript para expresiones regulares, mi expresión al principio era esta:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9_#%./\"-+]+(\\s{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_#%./\"-+]+)*"
```

Con esta cadena, acepto texto alfanumérico y los caracteres `#`, `$`, `.`, `/`, `"`, `-`, `+`, sin espacios delante y atrás y un solo espacio entre palabras. La función para comprobar que un texto coincide con dicho patrón es el siguiente:

```
bool GestionErrores::es_texto_caracteres_especiales(std::string texto)    
{
    bool retorno = false;

    try
    {
        std::regex expresion("[a-zA-Z0-9_#%./\"-+]+(\\s{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_#%./\"-+]+)*");
        std::smatch match;
        retorno = std::regex_match(texto, match, expresion);            
    }
    catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return retorno;
}
```

Expandí esta expresión para que acepte esos espacios para poder reemplazarlos y hacerla apta para reemplazar utilizando los paréntesis, y quedo así:

```
"(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_#%./\"-+]+)((\\s{1})(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_#%./\"-+]+))*(\\s*)"
```

Según la sintaxis de JavaScript, se puede utilizar como referencia los paréntesis para generar una sub-cadena nueva, un ejemplo en JavaScript en la [documentación de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace#Ejemplo:_Conectando_palabras_en_una_cadena) es:

```
var expresion = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var cadena = "John Smith";
var nuevaCadena = cadena.replace(expresion, "$2, $1");
print(nuevaCadena);
```

Como puedo notar, identifica los paréntesis de manera secuencial con $1, $2.. etc, pero, ¿Cómo diferencio paréntesis dentro de paréntesis? para la expresión que estoy utilizando, posee tres paréntesis dentro un paréntesis más grande:

```
"(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_#%./\"-+]+)((\\s{1})(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_#%./\"-+]+))*(\\s*)"
                                        ^^      
//Este parentesis es el problema, se encuentra dentro de otro parentesis mas grande
```

¿De que forma podría hacerlo, para que al final, la sub-cadena nueva no posea espacios delante ni atrás y un solo espacio entre palabras?.

---

## EDITADO 1

Quiero poder ingresar un texto de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y obtener como reemplazo un texto de la siguiente manera sin espacios delante y atrás y un solo espacio entre palabras:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quise realizarlo utilizando los paréntesis como referencia, porque de esta manera podría incluso cambiar el orden de texto si así quisiese, pero aún no lo tengo claro.

Primero porque el enumera las expresiones agrupadas por los paréntesis como $1, $2, $3... de manera secuencial, pero ¿Qué pasa con paréntesis dentro de paréntesis?, ya probé llamándolos $1.1 por ejemplo, y lo que hacia en el reemplazo era ponerme la expresión relacionada con $1 y al final el .1, por ejemplo mario.1, osea que no.

Segundo es el reemplazo en si, estoy realizando pruebas con esta expresión regular:

```
"(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(((\\s{1})(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))*)(\\s*)"
```

y esta es la función que utilizando para reemplazar:

```
void GestionErrores::quitar_espacios_inicio_fin(std::string &texto)
{
    std::string subString;

    try
    {
        std::regex expresion("(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(((\\s{1})(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))*)(\\s*)");
        std::smatch match;
        subString = std::regex_replace(texto, expresion, "$2$3");
        texto = subString;
    }
    catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

Desmenuzando la expresión regular que estoy utilizando,

- **$1** es `(\\s*)`
- **$2** es `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)`
- **$3** es `(((\\s{1})(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))*)`
- **$4** es `(\\s*)`

En mi función `quitar_espacios_inicio_fin` para reemplazar, estoy realizando pruebas al solo poner `$2$3` en `std::regex_replace`, quiere decir que mi sub-cadena sera exactamente la misma solo sin `$1` y `$4` que representan los espacios delante y atrás y efectivamente sucede así, me quita los espacio delante y atrás.

*Pero*, ¿Cómo puedo indicar los paréntesis que están dentro de paréntesis?, miren a `$3`, está lleno de expresiones agrupadas por paréntesis, y específicamente quiero deshacerme de una de ellas en la sub-cadena de reemplazo, de esta `(\\s*)`.

Ahora, si pude solucionar el problema de los espacios de más, con una idea surgida de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189830/eliminar-dos-o-mas-espacios-en-blanco-expresion-regular), *pero* no de la manera en que lo planteo, esta es la función que quedo:

```
void GestionErrores::quitar_espacios_inicio_fin(std::string &texto)
{
    std::string subString;

    try
    {
        std::regex expresion("(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(((\\s{1})(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))*)(\\s*)");
        std::regex expEspacios("(\\s{2,})");
        std::smatch match;
        subString = std::regex_replace(texto, expresion, "$2$3");
        subString = std::regex_replace(subString, expEspacios, " ");
        texto = subString;
    }
    catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

Explicándola brevemente, cómo acabe de mostrarlo, me deshago de los espacios delante y atrás. La expresión regular `(\\s{2,})` indica a dos o más espacios(aunque también indica tab, salto de línea, salto de página, retorno de carro) y reemplazo los espacios de dos o más, por un solo espacio.

Funciona, y salí de mi problema, pero sigue sin solucionar la duda que poseo, ¿Cómo indico expresiones agrupadas o paréntesis, dentro de otras expresiones agrupada o paréntesis?, comienzo a pensar que sencillamente no se puede, y enumera de manera global las expresiones agrupadas, y las expresiones dentro de otras expresiones sencillamente las ignora.

Una pregunta con una respuesta cerrada, ¿Se puede o no se puede?, y si se llega a poder, ¿Cómo?.

---

## EDITADO 2

Actualizando el código de la función con la respuesta dada, queda así:

```
void GestionErrores::quitar_espacios_inicio_fin(std::string &texto)
{
    std::string subString;        

    try
    {
        std::regex expEspacios("^ +| +$| +(?!\\S)");
        std::smatch match;
        subString = std::regex_replace(texto, expEspacios, "");
        texto = subString;
    }
    catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, podrías poner un ejemplo de entrada y el resultado esperado?

Comment: @Julio, listo, puedes echarle un ojo.

Comment: La solución no va en la pregunta, quítala de la pregunta y publícala como respuesta

Comment: @Aprendiz pero, el problema es que la solución de Julio es, no se puede hacer como quería y me platea otra manera de hacerlo, entonces quise hacer una pequeña conclusión.

Comment: Si tu tienes una solución propia debes publicarla como respuesta por favor

Comment: @Aprendiz no poseo una solución propia, terminé utilizando la planteada por Julio y en la conclusión mostré como quedo mi función con su solución, teniendo en cuenta que el solo plantea la expresión regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

Busca: `^ *| *$| +(?!\S)` con "flags" `m` y `g`.

Remplazar por: `(nada)`

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/xyFnY5/3/)

**Explicado**:

(nota: en la explicación, denoto los espacios como `[ ]` para que sean visibles)

```
# Una de las siguientes opciones:
  ^[ ]+       # Inicio de línea y 0 o más espacios
| [ ]+$       # o uno o más espacios y luego fin de línea
| [ ]+(?!\S)  # o uno o más espacios y luego no debe venir algo que no sea blanco
```

Comment: Mil veces mejor que la solución improvisada que yo plantee.